# retrieving values from ignite cache but Rdd don´t show values and long time Java

Tags: java, bigdata, ignite

I have an application that saves Rdd's spark with some values (key, value) to ignite cache, then I have another application that gets this cache ignite and extract these values (key, value), the problem is when you draw can not get the values and show them I'm using Java?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String dataset = args[1];
    String cacheName = "EXCHANGE_DEXL";

    // IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    // cfg.getCacheConfiguration();

    // Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(cfg);
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(args[0])) {

        System.out.println("Ignite inicializado");

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("partitioned");
        System.out.println("Spark configuração inicializada.");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        System.out.println("Spark context inicializado.");
        IgniteContext ic = new IgniteContext(sc.sc(), args[0]);
        System.out.println("Ignite Context inicializado.");

        save(sc, ic, cacheName, dataset);
        retrieve(ic, cacheName);

        ic.close(false);
        sc.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.err.println("ocorreu problema " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static void save(JavaSparkContext sc, IgniteContext ic, String cacheName, String dataset) {
    long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();

    IgniteRDD<Integer, String> igniteRDD = ic.fromCache(cacheName);

    System.out.println("IgniteRDD do cache init.");

    if (dataset == "0") {
        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://file");
    }
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("hdfs:file2");

    JavaRDD<String> rdd = lines.cache();
    // STEP-5: map input(T) into (K,V) pair
    // PairFunction<T, K, V>
    // T => Tuple2<K, V>
    long inicio2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> kv = rdd.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, Integer, String>() {
        public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String s) {
            String[] tokens = s.split(";"); // 1;314.996394;35.267357;1;2
            List<Tuple2<String, String>> list = new LinkedList<Tuple2<String, String>>();
            return new Tuple2<Integer, String>(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]), tokens[1]);
        }
    });
    long fim2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long total2 = fim2 - inicio2;
    System.out.println("Tempo Total JavaPairdd: " + total2 / 1000);
    igniteRDD.savePairs(kv.rdd(), false);
    // igniteRDD.saveValues(rdd);
    System.out.println("IgniteRDD save.");
    long fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long total = fim - inicio;
    System.out.println("Tempo Total: " + total / 1000);

}

private static void retrieve(IgniteContext ic, String cacheName) {

    long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Obtendo IgniteRDD salvo.");

    IgniteRDD<Integer, String> javaIRDDRet = ic.fromCache(cacheName);

    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, String>> javardd = javaIRDDRet.toJavaRDD();

    int j = (int) javardd.count();

    System.out.println("valor do count =" + j);

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {

        try {

            Tuple2<Integer, String> retorno2 = javardd.filter();

            System.out.println(retorno2._1 + " " + retorno2._2);
            i++;

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long total = fim - inicio;
    System.out.println("Tempo Total: " + total / 1000);
}
```

}

Comment: So what is the issue? Do you get incorrect output?

Comment: exactly, Valentin
in my output can not extract the values of Rdd, can not find a solution, could help me?

Comment: Can you provide the full test code that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: yes, I will edit the content above

Comment: the values contained in rdd slow enough to appear, why ?

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"? Can you elaborate?